# Update data in SQLite flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I have data, it`s list

```
static List<Map<String, dynamic>> defaultProducts = [
    {
      'name': 'product 1',
      'value': 0,
      'price': 0.0,
      'selected': 'false',
      'purchase': 'false'
    },
    {
      'name': 'product 2',
      'value': 3,
      'price': 570.0,
      'selected': 'true',
      'purchase': 'false'
    },
    {
      'name': 'product 3',
      'value': 2,
      'price': 980.0,
      'selected': 'true',
      'purchase': 'false'
    },
  ];
}
```

I process this data and filter it.

As a result, I get a filtered list.

I choose those that have the property **'selected': 'true',**

I need to do a function that would increment value by one and update 'price': 0.0,

I try to use forEach, my code

```
static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getSelectedData() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.query(
      'data',
      orderBy: 'value',
      where: 'selected = ?',
      whereArgs: ['true'],
    );
  }

Future<void> _updateSelectedProd() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    final _data = await SQLHelper.getSelectedData();
    _data.forEach((element) async {
      final data = {
        'price': 0.0,
        'value': int.parse(element['value']) + 1,
      };
      db.update('data', data, where: 'selected = ?', whereArgs: ['true']);
    });
    _refreshSelectedData();
    _calcSumPrices();
  }
```

The request works, but the problem is that the same number is added for each element. After execution, everyone will have value = 4

I need to increase each 'value' separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update condition should be more specific like

```
(..., where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: [element['name']]);
```

The way you're doing you're updating all the elements every iteration